# python print all words from list of a line

Tags: python, list

I am trying to code and print all keywords on a line from a list.I mean: i have a list `keywords=['bike','car','home']` 
i have a text file:

```
every one has bike and car
i have a bike
i am trying to get a car and home
```

Coding:

```
keywords=['bike','car','home']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:            
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
               a = key
               break
            else:
                a = 'nil'
        print a
```

my output prints only one key not all key present over list!
I mean my output expected is:

```
bike car
bike
car home
```

Instead ,i get now as:

```
bike
bike
car
```

How can i print all the keys from the lines?Please help! Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: You `break` on the first one, what did you expect?

Comment: you are overwriting a instead you could append the found key to a in the if case like a = a + ' ' + key

Comment: now i edited the code!

Comment: @user3914506: When people show you two problems in your code, and you only fix one of them, your code still isn't going to work.

Comment: Also, please don't edit your question so that the existing comments and answers are no longer relevant. That makes it useless to anyone coming along with the same question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate problems here, both of which need to be fixed.

First, as pointed out by @jonrsharpe, you `break` as soon as you find the first match, which means you're specifically telling Python to stop after the first match, so it's doing exactly what you ask. Just remove that `break`.

Second, as pointed out by @hasan, even without the `break`, for each key, you're replacing `a`, either with the new key, or with `nil`. So, you're just going to print out either `home` or `nil` every time. What you want to do is accumulate all of the matching keys. Like this:

```
matches = []
for key in keywords:
    if key in line:
        matches.append(key)
if matches:
    print ' '.join(matches)
else:
    print 'nil'
```

---

From your comment:

> small problem,if i have new line as 'car and bike',then its first printing 'bike car' instead of 'car bike'!

Think about what you're asking Python to do: You're going through the keys in `keywords`, and checking whether each one is found in `line`. So of course the order in which they're found will be the order they appear in `keywords`.

If you want them in the order they appear in the line instead, there are two options.

First, you can search through the `line`, looking for matches in `keywords`, instead of searching for `keywords`, looking for matches in `line`. If you only want to match complete words, and want duplicates to show up multiple times, this is dead simple:

```
for word in line.split():
    if word in keywords:
        matches.append(word)
```

If you want to match partial words (e.g., your existing code finds `car` in `"this program is designed for scaring small children"`, but the code I just gave will not), you can search all substrings instead of all words:

```
for i in range(len(line)):
    for key in keywords:
        if line[i:].startswith(key):
            matches.append(key)
```

If you only want to find each word once, you can check `if word not in matches` before appending it.

And so on. Whatever you want to add, you have to think through what the rule is before you can turn it into code, but usually it won't be very hard.

Comment: it works fine,but an small problem,if i have new line as 'car and bike',then its first printing 'bike car' instead of 'car bike'!

Comment: @user3914506: Of course. You're searching for the keys in the order they appear in `keywords`, so they're going to print out in the order they appear in `keywords`. If you want to search in the order they appear in the line, you need to, e.g., `split` the line into words, then search for each word to see if it appears in `keywords`.

Comment: thanks for the precise answering,it solved my problem,completely!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the order, you can make your `keywords` a set and search the intersection with the set of words in `line`:

```
keywords = set(['bike','car','home'])
with open('qwe.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print ' '.join(keywords & set(line.split())) or 'nil'
```

This is faster when your lines and `keywords` are big, since you don't have to iterate over the lists.

---

### Example

*input*

```
every one has bike and car
i have a bike
i am trying to get a car and home
i don't have any
```

*output*

```
car bike
bike
car home
nil
```

Comment: yes thank you so much,but i am expecting, the first line of output has to be 'bike car' but when new line in file like 'i have a car and bike' then only output should be 'car bike' but not for all lines!

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a to new keyword each time, rather than storing each one you see. Maybe make a new list each time you look at a new line and append the words you find:

```
keywords=['bike','car','home']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        a = []
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
               a.append(key)
        if len(a) > 0:
            print ' '.join(a)
```

You might also see if a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) can build that array for you in a single line. Haven't tried it but it might be possible. Good luck!